# Azure Maps Route Directions - Bad Request

Tags: azure, maps, azure-maps

Can anyone possible tell me what is wrong with this coordinate: -21.186924,-41.224376
google maps says it's ok!

Azure API Returns Bad Request!

https://atlas.microsoft.com/route/directions/json?api-version=1&subscription-key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&query=-21.156265,-41.2771530:-21.186924,-41.224376&routeRepresentation=polyline&travelMode=car&&view=Auto&computeBestOrder=true

Message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "400 BadRequest",
    "message": "Bad request: one or more parameters were incorrectly specified or are mutually exclusive."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your coordinates are in the Atlantic ocean. Note that Azure Maps aligns with the GIS standard of "longitude, latitude" which aligns with "x, y", while Google Maps uses "latitude, longitude"

Comment: I don't think that's the problem...

When I invert the coordinates the error gets even worse...
example:
-41.2771530,-21.156265:-41.224376,-21.186924

-> {"error":{"code":"400 BadRequest","message":"The provided coordinates in query are invalid, out of range, or not in the expected format"}}

...using another coordinate nearby, it works...
example:
-21.156265,-41.2771530:-21.164605,-41.247068

Comment: Ok, I must have been confusing the services. Looking at "-21.186924,-41.224376", it is no where near any well known roads, thus why the routing service failed for you initially. If you look in the map you will see there is nothing until you switch into aerial view, then you will see some dirt roads. I'll pass this on to the data provider to see if they would add those.

Comment: Any predictions for the correction? because the error still continues

Comment: This type of issue is not something that can be resolved quickly and requires people to physically drive and map out the roads. You can report the issue here and it will provide you a URL you can use to monitor the status.https://feedback.azuremaps.com